# Identifying a DOM element without an ID value

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-maestro

I regularly use a web app from Invisalign® to set up orthodontic cases. I use Keyboard Maestro to make keyboard shortcuts within the app by activating JavaScript.

An example of the JavaScript triggered by keyboard maestro:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').click();
```

The web app was recently updated and there is no longer a button ID. Thus, the getElementByID is no longer functioning.

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
document.getElementByClass('myClass').click();
```

(I have tried c01143 and c0012)

An example of the HTML for the page is:

```
<div class='c0012'>
        <button type="button" tabindex="-1" data-qa-name="lower" data-qa-toggled="false" class="c0180 c01149 c01151">
            <div class="c01143">
                <svg class="c0189 c0191" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M2,13 L22,13 L22,16 L2,16 L2,13 Z M8,8 L16,8 L16,11 L8,11 L8,8 Z"></path></svg>
            </div>
        <span class="c01142">Lower</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I have also tried:

```
document.getElementBydata-qa-name('lower').click();
```

That also doesn't work. Hopefully someone can help out with what might be a very simple solution. Although I know some HTML and CSS my JavaScript is almost nonexistent.

Comment: How about document.getElementsByClassName('c0180 c01149 c01151')[0].click();

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: You may want to be careful about automating these kinds of things -- check their Terms of Service to be sure it's allowed. There may be a reason they redesigned their site to eliminated IDs...

Answer (score 5):

The non-descriptive class names (e.g., `c0012`, `c01143`) strongly indicate that, somewhere in the site's stack, the HTML/CSS/JS is being dynamically compiled/generated. As such, you should expect that these identifiers could change drastically and quite frequently & you shouldn't rely on them in your snippet.

---

#### Method #1 - `document.querySelector()` using `data-qa-name`

You can use the `document.querySelector()` method to identify based on the `button` tag, the `button` `type` value, as well as the custom `data-qa-name` attribute. The following demonstrates that this method works to identify the element without relying on the class name or the (no longer-existent) ID value:

```js
(() => {
  console.log(document.querySelector("button[type='button'][data-qa-name='lower']"));
})();
```

```html
<div class='c0012'>
  <button type="button" tabindex="-1" data-qa-name="lower" data-qa-toggled="false" class="c0180 c01149 c01151">
            <div class="c01143">
                <svg class="c0189 c0191" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M2,13 L22,13 L22,16 L2,16 L2,13 Z M8,8 L16,8 L16,11 L8,11 L8,8 Z"></path></svg>
            </div>
        <span class="c01142">Lower</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

You would lift and shift the above by simply calling `click()` on the identified element, as you had previously:

```
document.querySelector("button[type='button'][data-qa-name='lower']").click();
```

---

#### Method #2 - `document.querySelectorAll()`, filtered using `.innerText` value

While from what you've posted there isn't any strong indication that this `data-qa-name` attribute would change in either name or value, you can also target the element based on its `innerText` value similar to the following:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("button[type='button']")].find(function (ele) {return ele.innerText === "Lower"})).click();
```

The following snippet, while it appears succinct, performs the following steps:

1. Enumerates all `button` elements with an attribute `type` of `button` into an Array structure.
2. Finds and returns the first element in the array that has an `innerText` property equal to the string `Lower`.
3. Executes the `click()` method on the identified button.

The only scenario in which *this* particular snippet wouldn't work to your requirements would be if there are buttons appearing somewhere in the DOM tree before the intended button element that also have an `innerText` property equal to the string "Lower". You'll have to perform a small amount of testing to confirm which of these snippets will work most consistently in your scenario.

---

#### Further reading

Considering your self-professed limited understanding of JavaScript, you may wish to consult the following MDN documentation pages to get a better grasp on the methods and linguistic conventions leveraged above:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Glossary - `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array)
- [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Thank you so much esqew. I just wrapped up my day with patients and tried Method 1. It worked like a charm. I am going to look at method 2 and do some of the suggested further reading. A sa simple orthodontist, it's fun to venture out of my bubble and learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

With [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you can use CSS style selectors to target an element. In the example below it select the first button inside the element with the `.c0012` class.

```
document.querySelector('.c0012 button').click();
```

Comment: While technically correct for the HTML snippet posted, it's likely these classes are dynamically-generated and would change frequently.